How to set up pgbouncer in a docker-compose setup for Airflow and a front/back
I'm running a distributed Airflow setup using docker-compose. Everything goes well but when the dags ar executing i get this error "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution", this is my docker-compose
x-airflow-common:
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  &airflow-common
  build:
    context: airflow
  platform: linux/amd64
  environment: &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'

    # AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER: '/opt/airflow/dags'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  env_file: &airflow-common-env-file
    - .env
  volumes:
    - ./cafe_dags/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - airflow-logs:/opt/airflow/logs

  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on: &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-airflow:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow" ]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always
  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD",
          "curl",
          "--fail",
          "http://localhost:8080/health"
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    env_file: *airflow-common-env-file
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"'
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"'
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_MIGRATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow
  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

I read that the solution for this could be use pgbouncer but I do not know how to set up that, this could be maybe what I have to do?
pgbouncer:
    image: "bitnami/pgbouncer:1.16.0"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRESQL_HOST: "postgres"
      POSTGRESQL_USERNAME: airflow
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRESQL_PORT: ${PSQL_PORT}
      PGBOUNCER_DATABASE: airflow
      PGBOUNCER_AUTH_TYPE: "trust"
      PGBOUNCER_IGNORE_STARTUP_PARAMETERS: "extra_float_digits"
    ports:
      - '1234:1234'
    depends_on:
      - postgres

and change
AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow

for
AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@pgbouncer/airflow
AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@pgbouncer/airflow

I do not know.
